# Number of training images required for face recognition using opencv with python

Tags: python, opencv, face-recognition

I am able to detect as well as recognize the faces using python and opencv. But not satisfied with the accuracy. I tried using 20 images for the first trial. then 30 and finally 500. but the accuracy of recognizing the faces is not that much satisfactory. 
I shows wrong recognition for some faces. I tried using confidence threshold too.

```
        if id_ == 1 and confidence < 60:
            show_profile(1)

        elif id_ == 2 and confidence < 60:
            show_profile(2)

        elif id_ == 3 and confidence < 60:
            show_profile(3)
```

Here is the code for displaying the recognized image. get_profile fetches the info from database.

```
def show_profile(profile_id):  # shows id related information on image
    cv2.putText(frame, 'Name: ' + get_profile(profile_id)[1], (x, y + h + 30),
                font, 0.5, (0, 200, 0), 1)
    cv2.putText(frame, 'Age: ' + str(get_profile(profile_id)[2]), (x, y + h + 50),
                font, 0.5, (0, 200, 0), 1)
    cv2.putText(frame, 'Gender: ' + str(get_profile(profile_id)[3]), (x, y + h + 70),
                font, 0.5, (0, 200, 0), 1)
    cv2.putText(frame, 'Designation: ' + str(get_profile(profile_id)[4]), (x, y + h + 90),
                font, 0.5, (0, 200, 0), 1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have probably reached the limits of opencv. Try to use better models. Accuracies on benchmarks can be found for example here: https://www.sighthound.com/technology/face-recognition/benchmarks/pubfig200

Comment: Could it be done without internet? I do not wish to use their api for face recognition.

Comment: Yes, you do not need internet. Try for example this https://github.com/davidsandberg/facenet

Comment: So to conclude, opencv has limitations over face recognition but have advantages as well (it can be trained very easily) whereas in case of tensorflow it needs training but gives more accurate result than opencv